# How to cache posts based on $_GET? Option name is too long? Options / transients

Tags: options, cache, transient

I have a search feature set up that is fairly expensive and I want to cache the results, based on the $_get string, like: `?search_type=product&relation=or&date=all&s=tagsearch&merchcat=cotton&brand=brandx&color=blue&etc=morestuff`

So, i'm trying to cache the array of posts that I get:

```
if (false === ( $products = get_transient($name) ) ) {
    $products = getproducts();
    set_transient($name, $products, 60*60*12);
}
```

for the transient name, I've been trying various things like

```
$name= base64_encode(serialize($_GET));
```

But, I'm running into the problem of the option name getting truncated and possibly encoded, slashed, etc.

How would you go about solving this?

Comment: Have you tried `md5($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);` or `md5(implode('|', ksort($_GET)))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the relevant bits of the [database description for that table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_options).

```
Field           Type        
option_name     varchar(64)      
option_value    longtext
```

The key is 64 characters max. The value is longtext which should be more than you need.

To have you caching work, you need a unique value for the key, but it doesn't have to be readable. My suggestion would be to hash the `GET` string. It should be unique and well shy of 64 characters.

Instead of this: `$name= base64_encode(serialize($_GET));`

Try this: `$name= wp_hash($_GET);`

Proof of concept using the sample `GET` string above:

```
$str = '?search_type=product&relation=or&date=all&s=tagsearch&merchcat=cotton&brand=brandx&color=blue&etc=morestuff';
var_dump(base64_encode(serialize($str)));
// vs
var_dump(wp_hash($str));
```

Edit based on the discussion below (thanks @G-M):

The order of the arguments in the `GET` string could effect the hash values. The safe thing to do is to normalize the array. The following should do that:

```
$str = $_GET;
ksort($str);
$str = add_query_arg($str,'');
$str = wp_hash($str);
var_dump($str);
```

All arguments are preserved, even the empty ones, which seem to be what the OP wants, though I personally believe that running the array through `array_filter` to remove empty values would actually provide better caching.

```
$str = $_GET;
$str = array_filter($str);
ksort($str);
$str = add_query_arg($str,'');
var_dump(wp_hash($str));
```

No data validation/sanitization was attempted.

When you save that key to the database, I would also suggest prepending a string to make it identifiable-- something like `$str = 'my_plugin_slug'.$str` before saving it.

Comment: Problem with this is that same arguments in different order will result in different hash, even if the query is the same.

Comment: @G-M : Yes. Presumably there is a form or something generating the query so the order should be fairly reliable but to be sure you'd have to normalize the array, certainly. I should include that in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $newget);
ksort($newget);
$str =  http_build_query($newget);
$name = wp_hash($str);`
Should normalize the array, yes?

Comment: I am unsetting $_GET['s'] in some cases, which is why I went thru the string->array->string process.  I just want to be sure I'm getting the whole querystring.